# Solving non linear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality

$f(x)=-x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \quad \text{for } x>0$ is a striclty monotone function with  satisfying 
$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=+\infty$$ and $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=-\infty$$
Thus $f(x)=c$ has a unique solution for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$...

Is it possible to solve $f(x)=c$ explicitely?

Answer (score 2):

To solve it, note that

$$c+x= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
Squaring this equation and moving terms around yields
$$x^3+2cx^2+c^2x-1=0$$
Which is a solvable cubic.

Comment: Slightly different solution:  let $y= \sqrt{x}$ so that $x= y^2$.  The equation can be written $-y^2+ \frac{1}{y}= c$.  Multiplying both sides by y (and noting that y cannot be 0) we get the cubic equation $y^3+ cy- 1= 0$.   This can be solved using the "cubic formula" (https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/).